# Как сделать ИИ как в shadow fight?

Tags: unity3d

у объекта есть набор анимаций (атака, передвижение и тп) каким способом можно реализовать ИИ которое будет выбирать действие в зависимости от чего либо? или хотябы рандомно в unity(2д игра)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дать отслеживание растояния и в зависимости от него сделать возможности ии, подключить модуль рандома и сделать его дефствия в зависимости от этих двух факторов

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: как лучше всего реализовать отслеживание расстояния?

Comment: @ULYANARSL, я не пишу игры, но премерно представляю как это делается, скорее всего в растоянии между хитбоксами

Comment: ну что нужно искать расстояние меджу коллайдерами понятно, просто я не знаю нужного метода

Comment: @ULYANARSL, указываете physic = '                 void Start()
{
    physic = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}'  ,потом обнаруживаю координаты вектора главного объекта, потом описывал срабатывание скрипта